# How to add elements to Viewpager dynamically android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using viewpager to swipe between view.Initially i'm loading 5 items to viewpager.When scrolling 5th page i'm downloading remaining 20 elements from server.How to acheive that.I have enable notifyDatasetChanged().It is also not working.

I have tried viewpager.setAdapter(adapter).It is working but it's scrolls to the 0th position.

How to acheive this?

Thanks in adavance:)

Comment: You can use the `setCurrentItem()` method on your `ViewPager`, just put in parameter the index of the page you want to scroll to.

Comment: I have tried that but if i use viewpager.setadapter(adapter) it will scroll to 0th position automatically.At that time setCurrentItem() is not working.

Comment: can you post your code.